# How do you say "once every x days/weeks/etc"?

Tags: grammar

Could anyone help me with this translation? I think once per week is "shuu ichi" but with days in particular I really don't remember how to say it.

Comment: Are you looking for おき and ごと. Check those words and how they are used.

Comment: ^ But "once a week" "twice a week" "once a day" "twice a day" etc. cannot be expressed with おき or ごと, right?

Comment: @chocolate the OP is not asking for twice a day. Check the title: "once every x days/weeks/etc"

Answer (score 9):

The most generic and useful pattern is `number + counter + に + number + 回/度`.

- 2年に1回 once in two years
- 6週間に1回 once in six weeks
- [1月]{ひとつき}に3回 ／ [1か月]{いっかげつ}に3回 three times a month
- 1年に2回 twice a year
- [1日]{いちにち}に3回 three times a day
- [2日]{ふつか}に3回 three times in two days

There are some irregular readings when referring to a time span. See the last part of [this page](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/date_time).

You can also say 日【ひ】にn回, 週(に)n回, 月【つき】(に)n回, 年(に)n回 (but not 時間n回, 日n回, 週間n回, etc).

> - 1週間に5回バイトをする = 週(に)5回バイトをする to work part-time five days a week
> - 年(に)1度の総会 the annual general meeting

週一【しゅういち】 is a bit slangy and colloquial phrase that means 1週間に1回 (once a week). You can also say 週一【しゅういち】 ～ 週七【しゅうなな】, 月一【つきいち】, 年一【ねんいち】. (But 月三/年四/etc are rare and you should usually say 月に3回/年4回 instead)

> - 週七【しゅうなな】でバイトをする to work part-time seven days a week
> - 月一【つきいち】のミーティング monthly meeting

In addition, there are 隔日【かくじつ】, 隔週【かくしゅう】, 隔月【かくげつ】, 隔年【かくねん】 which mean "every other ～".

> 隔週のミーティング biweekly meeting

Comment: does the use of かくしゅう ever pose an ambiguity problem for native speakers (隔週、各週)

Comment: 隔週 is [かくしゅう]{LHHHH} while 各週 is [かくしゅう]{HLLLL}, and 各週 is very rarely used IMO (we use 毎週).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I'll take it as a species of grammatical overgeneralization I've committed as a foreigner then (not to be outdone by the span nearly a decade ago where I way saying [今年]{コンネン})

Comment: @naruto You made your response so awesome that you forgot to answer the question. How would you say "once every x days/weeks/etc" ?

Comment: @oldergod I think the first part answer the question. x年に1回 / x週に1回 will do.