# What is the meaning of 月 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, readings, conjugations, manga

★please note: if it’s possible, I wouldn’t want the whole sentence translated as I want to do it myself. I’d prefer to have information about my questions with examples in other sentences than this one. I learn more than when I’m just given an answer. Of course, if it can’t be explained without explaining the whole sentence it’s ok too!

保険制度『の』おかげ『で』患者『の』支払う医療費『は』月数万程度［だ]『が』
[Page in the left, second panel from the top, first bubble on the right.](https://www.sukima.me/bv/t/blackjackniyoroshiku/v/1/s/3/p/14)

月 can mean moon but that’s not it here so I’d logically narrow it down to the meaning of month. But considering what comes after, I don’t know how to word it!

数万 means “tens of thousands” and 程度 means “degree”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 月【つき】 means "per month". You may know [に is used for this purpose](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37059/5010), but [1日]{いちにち}, 週, 月 and 年 work like a shorthand and you don't have to say に. (いち must be used only before 日. 週/月/年 is preceded by nothing.)

Examples:

- 年1回
  once a year
- 1日3錠
  3 tables/pills per day
- 1日1時間
  an hour a day (not "a day and an hour"; see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58968/5010))
- 月5本
  5 episodes/lessons/etc a month
- 週5日
  five days a week

---

程度 in this context is "about" or "roughly". So 月数万程度 means "about tens of thousands of yen a month".

Comment: Ok but I'm not sure I understand how it relates to 数万 and 程度. Also there's no number before 月 so does it still apply?

Also, you're saying that the 1 before 月 is supposed to be understood just like に doesn't have to be said.

Comment: @EtienneZizka I didn't notice you also got 程度 wrong. See my edit. No number has to come before 月/週/年 as long as it means "a month/week/year". When you want to say something complicated like "twice in every three weeks", you have to be explicit and say 3週に2回.

Comment: Thanks, I supposed you guessed 円 even if it wasn’t mentioned in the context.

Comment: @EtienneZizka Oh, I thought it was obvious because it's about 患者の支払う医療費 (and the characters were Japanese).