# What is the difference between 週一回 and 週に一回?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I have seen 週一回 and 週に一回. I was wondering if anyone could explain the difference.

Examples:

- トレーニングは週2回です。
- 週に一回ダンスを習っています。

I couldn't find an answer, I'm sorry this question has already been answered.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37059/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning, but the form without に only takes a pure unit with no number.

> （年二回／年に二回／一年に二回）起こる。
> （× 二年一回／二年に一回）起こる。
>
> （週二回／週に二回／一週間に二回）起こる。
> （× 二週間一回／二週間に一回）起こる。
>
> （一日二回／日【ひ】に二回／一日に二回）起こる。 ← a little irregular
> （× 二日一回／二日に一回）起こる。
>
> （一時間二回／× 時間に二回／一時間に二回）起こる。 ← 時間 would mean "time"
> （× 二時間一回／二時間に一回）起こる。

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation & examples!